# Flutter web GestureDetector: detect mouse wheel events

Tags: flutter, scroll

I am developing a flutter app for web, and I am trying to execute a callback method when I scroll the mouse wheel inside a widget (which is not a scrolling widget).

I am aware of the `MouseRegion` widget, and using a `Listener` as its child I can detect `onPointerSignal` events. This works fine when the `Listener`'s child is a scrollable widget, such a `ListView`, but it does not work if this widget is not scrollable.

What I ideally would like to have is a widget similar to `GestureDetector`, with callback methods that are similar to `onPanStart`, `onPanUpdate` and `onPanEnd`, but instead happening on mouse wheel events (or, in the same way, for trackpad scrolling events on laptops).

Anybody knows how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

`Listener` does not need any parent.
A widget like the following can be used, which wraps its child in a `Listener` and calls the given callback when a `PointerScrollEvent` is received:

```dart
class ScrollDetector extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(PointerScrollEvent event) onPointerScroll;
  final Widget child;

  const ScrollDetector({
    Key key,
    @required this.onPointerScroll,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
        if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) onPointerScroll(pointerSignal);
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's a complete example on DartPad.](https://dartpad.dev/5ef1303df51e9b214d4a9a219af768b4)

Comment: your code works perfectly. However in the DartPad example you provided, if I omit the `color: Colors.green` line, it stops working. Why does it work only when a color is provided?

Comment: @DaniS. From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html): By default, containers return false for all hit tests. If the color property is specified, the hit testing is handled by ColoredBox, which always returns true. If the decoration or foregroundDecoration properties are specified, hit testing is handled by Decoration.hitTest.

Comment: It looks like this will only work on widgets that listen to touch input.

Comment: I thought of a workaround for no scrolling over `HTMLView` by displaying a `PointerInterceptor` over the view when user scrolls, but, first, the listener doesn't work when the cursor is over the HTMLView which defies the purpose of this for me and second, it doesn't notify when the even stops/ends that even if the user had scrolled over any other component, the `PointerInterceptor` doesn't hide which makes the HtmlView unusable. It's sad that's none of the WYSIWYG editor works properly in Flutter web.