# swipe from the left to return to the previous style iOS screen Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, controller, swipe

in ios, if I swipe starting from the left of the screen and fall towards the center it goes back from the view. now I wanted to replicate the same thing in Flutter to my app, as I have the top left button to go back classic, but I would also like to have the ios style where you can go back even by swiping from the left. how can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this example that i have created using the Gesture detector:

You can use this widget at the top of the page so that it can detect the swipes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text("Next Page"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        // Note: Sensitivity is integer used when you don't want to mess up vertical drag
        int sensitivity = 8;
        if (details.delta.dx > sensitivity) {
          // Right Swipe

        } else if (details.delta.dx < -sensitivity) {
          //Left Swipe
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      }

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know this is what you are trying to implement

Comment: do i have to implement this to every class i have where i do a back? or if I do it in the main takes it in all?

Comment: its on you how to implement it, For the last page which is in the stack you can use the willpopscope to give a popup would you like to exit.

Comment: you can create your custom stateful widget where you can overide that method and user as per your needs.

Comment: @SagarAcharya - Can we add Gesture detection mechanism in flutter web view app??

Comment: @PARASGUPTA i have not worked on  flutter web yet but maybe this might work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985580/flutter-web-gesturedetector-detect-mouse-wheel-events

Answer (score 1):

tried this and works, on screen 1 you're navigating from add this line on your **gesture detector.**

```
onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.delta.direction > 0) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
    }
  },
```

On Page 2,  on build context, add this line

```
    onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {},
onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
   if (details.delta.direction <= 0) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
    }
},
```

Full code snippet below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swipe_detection_example/page2.dart';

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {},
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.direction > 0) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Page 1'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swipe_detection_example/page2.dart';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {},
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.direction <= 0) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Page 2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```